# Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument

Tags: r

In the code below, I am trying to cycle through csv files and calculate the correlation between two columns for each file. The results are being stored in an empty vector.

For example: the first file has name "001.csv". The for loop will calculate the correlation between the 2nd and 3rd column and store it in the 1st position of the results vector. This will continue to iterate until to the end of the loop.

For some reason the following error keep occuring:
`Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument`

The code I am trying to execute is:

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0) {
        ## defining the directory
          path = paste("C:/Users/name/Desktop/R/R Working Directory/",directory,"/", sep="", collapse="")
          directory1 <- dir(path, pattern=".csv")

          data.set <- complete(directory,)                  ##calling in the dataset to find correlation on
          data.setDIM <- dim(data.set)                      ##using the dim to filter data in for loop
          filter.data <- data.frame(matrix(,,2))
          result <- vector()    

          for(i in i:data.setDIM[1])
            {   if( data.set[i,2] >= threshold)
                    { filter.data[i,1]<-data.set[i,1]
                      filter.data[i,2]<-data.set[i,2] }
            }
          filter.data <- na.omit(filter.data)           ##removing the NA values

        ## Performing corr() function. I will use the 1st column of filter.data to identify the files to read and perform calc on.


         for(j in c(filter.data[1]))
            {   file <- na.omit(read.csv(paste(path,directory1[j],sep="",colapse="")))
                result[j] <- cor(file[2],file[3])
            }

         result
    }
```

The `c(filter.data[1])` gives me a vector of integers that I want to index through. I've printed out an example below.

```
[1]  21  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39
 [19]  41  44  45  47  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62
 [37]  63  64  66  67  68  71  72  74  75  76  77  78  80  83  84  86  87  88
 [55]  89  91  93  94  96  97  98  99 103 104 105 108 109 110 111 112 113 114
 [73] 115 116 117 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 127 128 131 132 133 136 138 139
 [91] 140 141 142 143 144 145 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 156 158 160 164
[109] 165 166 167 168 170 171 172 173 174 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184
[127] 185 186 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203
[145] 205 209 210 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 225 227 228 229
[163] 230 231 232 234 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 252 253
[181] 254 255 257 258 260 262 263 265 266 267 268 269 270 271 272 273 277 279
[199] 287 299 300 301 302 303 305 306 307 309 310 312 313 314 315 318 320 321
[217] 322 325 326 327 328 329 330 331
```

Comment: Look at the values of `paste(path,directory1[j],sep="",colapse="")` in your loop and make sure they look like valid file names. The error indicates somewhere you are specifying a bad path to a file.

Comment: Thanks for rapid response MrFlick....

Comment: ... The function above creates a vector of all column names that have the correct directory..... "C:/Users/name/Desktop/R/R Working Directory/specdata/023.csv"..... if i insert that line into the run prompt, it works...